# IBM Watson Chatbot unable to connect to server

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I am trying to integrate a Chatbot on my website. I followed [this tutoria](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/create-a-covid-19-chatbot-embedded-on-a-website/)l to set up the Watson Chatbot.

The bot is working as expected on the IBM cloud platform. And all my credentials are correct to set up the env.

However when I run the chatbot in my localhost:3000, I am not able to connect to the server. When I try to post a message to the bot for some reason I can not connect to the server and generate a session id.

this is the input JSON:

```
{
 "session_id": null,
 "input": {
           "message_type": "text",
           "text": "covid"
          }
}
```

And the console is giving me this message: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'session_id' of undefined`.

Would anyone know what could have gone wrong in my app?

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the question. I wrote the article. Can you please dm me on twitter @lidderupk. I can try and debug with you. When you say it is working on IBM Cloud, do you mean the node.js application on IBM Cloud or from the try in panel inside Watson assistant?

Comment: hi, @U-L  thank you for commenting on my question. I meant the bot worked successfully in the panel inside Watson assistant. the node.js starter-kit ran but it's not connecting to the server. I kept getting 'null' session id as I posted the messages.

Comment: Don't forget if you solve it offline, write an answer and close it off.